# Identify: time travelling game

Tags: identify-this-game

The game was played with a whole bunch of cards with historical events on them. Each event had two versions, one on each side of the card, and you could travel through time turning cards over to representing altering the past, in order to achieve some goal given to you at the beginning. Certain events contradicted each other, however, and when they both existed this created a paradox. If enough paradoxes occurred the timeline would explode and everyone lost.

Can anyone identify this game for me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like [Chrononauts](http://www.looneylabs.com/games/chrononauts).

From the official description:

> What would YOU do with a Time Machine? Would you stop the sinking of the Titanic? Prevent the assassination of JFK? Kill Hitler before WWII? These are just a few of the possibilities in Chrononauts, the award-winning card game of time travel. To win, you must change history at key points called Linchpins, so that history transforms into the Alternate Reality your character calls home. You can also win by collecting a specific set of Artifacts, such as a live dinosaur, the Mona Lisa, and an unpublished Shakespearean play. But be careful - **if you create too many paradoxes, you could destroy the entire universe**!

Comment: After looking it up, yeah that looks correct!